find_elements only gets the first element when using Selenium
I have a Python program that uses undetected Chromedriver to scrape product data from Walmart. The following is a simplified version of my code, but it only gets the first element. Can someone show me where the issue is?
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import undetected_chromedriver as uc


url='https://www.walmart.com/search?q=lego&facet=retailer_type%3AWalmart'

driver = uc.Chrome(enable_cdp_events=True)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

sleep(5)
for _ in range(3):
    try:
        scroll_value = driver.execute_script("return document.body.clientHeight;")
        driver.execute_script(f"return window.scrollBy(0, {str(scroll_value)})")
        sleep(1)
    except:
        pass

items_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div"))).find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid="list-view"]')

for raw_item in items_list:
    product_name = WebDriverWait(raw_item, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[2]/span/span"))).text.strip()
    print(product_name)


driver.quit()


EC.presence_of_element_located tries to locate a single element

OK, I change it to this, but it's same like before: items_list = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid="list-view"]')

I found a solution using bs4, thanks for the reply
